# Having Trouble in loading QVGA and HVGA emulators

Tags: android

Can anyone please help me? I'm trying to test my android application on different emulators (HVGA, QVGA and WVGA800). WVGA800 is loading properly but HVGA and QVGA are not. whenever I try to open these emulators(HVGA, QVGA), screens are pretty messed up and are not showing any application properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been resolved by creating new AVD. While creating AVD I was entering resolution manually, which was causing problem. Now I've created new AVDs by using built-in skin resolution as HVGA and QVGA. Both these emulators are working properly now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using images in you application then use 9 patch images which will set your layout according to screen size.

you can also provide different size of drawbles for various screen sizes in folder named drawable-ldpi, drawable-hdpi etc.. under res folder.

Comment: Thank you Sharmilee, I've already tried by providing different sizes of these in drawable-lpi and drawable-hdpi but the problem is with the emulators. Whenever I try to load these emulators(HVGA, QVGA), some part of screen is hidden within the borders no mater what size of emulator screen I'm using.

Comment: then try on real device. if it happens same there also, then problem is  with your code.

Comment: Thank you, It was working fine when I tried on real devices. I've created new AVDs by using built-in skin resolution as HVGA and QVGA. Both these emulators are working properly now.